# Swift Class Custom Type Property

Tags: swift, class, properties

I am having trouble with Swift class properties and I have no idea what to search.

I want to create something like this:

```
defenceSystem.status = status.online
defenceSystem.status = status.offline
defenceSystem.status = status.destroyed
```

So basically I want the `status` property (or class; not sure what it should be) to have 3 values: `online`, `offline` and `destroyed`.

But I want those 3 properties to have a custom type, not String, Int or anything else. Basically I don't want them to store anything. Just to act like flags.

I thought that I should write something like this:

```
class defenceSystem {
    class status {
    // Declare the 3 status types
    }
    var status = status()
    defenceSystem.status = status.online
}
```

I tried just writing `var online` but Xcode says it requires a type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of an `enum` to hold the three different states. E.g.

```
class DefenceSystem {
    enum Status {
        case Online
        case Offline
        case Destroyed
    }

    var status: Status

    init(status: Status) {
        self.status = status
    }
}

let defenceSystem = DefenceSystem(status: .Online)

print(defenceSystem.status) // Online
defenceSystem.status = .Offline
print(defenceSystem.status) // Offline
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  enum Status
    {
        case online
        case offline
        case destroyed
    }

    class defenceSystem:<Your Super class>
    {
          var status:Status

    }

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let defence = defenceSystem();

        defence.status = Status.online
        print(defence.status)
        defence.status = Status.offline
        print(defence.status)
        defence.status = Status.destroyed
        print(defence.status)

     }
}
```

Use the enumeration for the status with all option defined and then create a property of enumeration and set the value in enumeration as you needed.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html

I Hope your requirement is fulfilled.